# apache htaccess have certain url matches load a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I make certain url regex matches load one file?

For example:

`.com/people`, `.com/people/john`, `.com/people/*` => all load `./people.php`

and

`.com/animals`, `.com/pokemon` => both load `./index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea to have many routes leading to same content (this leads to **duplicate content** which is bad for referencing)

Anyway, here is the code that provides what you asked (put this code into your htaccess, which has to be in root folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^people/? /people.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(animals|pokemon)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I see where I was confused, I'll give this a try